# Trying to save HDF5 file in ROS node; .h5 file not being saved

Tags: python, numpy, ros, hdf5

I am using ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04. I am running a ros node which saves odometry data in a logfile. The log file successfully saves the odometry data; it looks like this:

```
  pose: 
  position: 
    x: 0.0027880480174993327
    y: -0.0029414520079247327
    z: 0.00563770744057384
  orientation: 
    x: 0.0027310495883615888
    y: 0.001136773836533139
    z: -0.0004563577307679678
    w: 0.9999955204154727, header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 1657741393
    nsecs: 358656466
  frame_id: "map"
```

The file extension is .log for the above portion. When I try to save the odometry data in the form of a .h5 file or a .npy file, no error appears on my terminal but the saved odometry files are nowhere to be found.

I see that the "odomarray" numpy array is being generated, but it is not being saved as a .hf file when ROS is shut down or when the node is shut down. Please help Please see my code:

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from nav_msgs.msg import Path
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry

import numpy as np
from numpy import savetxt, save
import h5py

odomdata = np.zeros((1,8))

global hf
hf = h5py.File('odomData.h5', 'w')

def callback(data):
    global odomdata

    # rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + 'data: %s', data.data)  # for String
    # rospy.loginfo(data.pose.pose)  # for Odometry

    rospy.loginfo(data.poses)  # for Path

    x_pos = data.poses[-1].pose.position.x
    y_pos = data.poses[-1].pose.position.y
    z_pos = data.poses[-1].pose.position.z

    x_orient = data.poses[-1].pose.orientation.x
    y_orient = data.poses[-1].pose.orientation.y
    z_orient = data.poses[-1].pose.orientation.z
    w_orient = data.poses[-1].pose.orientation.w

    sec = data.poses[-1].header.stamp.secs
    nsec = data.poses[-1].header.stamp.nsecs * (10**-9)

    float_time = sec + nsec

    odomarray = np.array([[float_time, x_pos, y_pos, z_pos, x_orient, y_orient, z_orient, w_orient]])
    # print(odomarray)

    odomdata = np.append(odomdata, odomarray, axis=0)
    save('odomData.npy', odomdata)
    print("I'M SAVING NPY NOW 1")
    # print(odomdata)


def listener():

    rospy.init_node('odomlistener')

    # rospy.Subscriber('ssl_slam_odom_estimation_node', String, callback)  #subscribe to odometry topic;
    rospy.Subscriber('/ssl_slam/trajectory', Path, callback)
    # rospy.Subscriber('odom', Odometry, callback)

    save('odomData.npy', odomdata)
    print("I'M SAVING NPY NOW 2")

    if rospy.is_shutdown():  # trying to save the data upon closing
        save('odomData.npy', odomdata)
        print("I'M SAVING NPY NOW 3")

        hf.create_dataset('dataset_1', data=odomdata)
        hf.close()
        print("I'M SAVING H5 NOW 1")

    rospy.spin()  # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        listener()

    finally:
        save('odomData.npy', odomdata)
        print("I'M SAVING NPY NOW 4")

        hf.create_dataset('dataset_1', data=odomdata)
        hf.close()
        print("I'M SAVING H5 NOW 2")
```

Comment: How are you terminating this?  Are you sure one of your two "save" clauses is getting executed?  You should add `print("I'M SAVING NOW")` in both cases so you can see if it gets there.

Comment: That's a really helpful point -- I am not sure if either one of the two "save" clauses is being executed. I'll try adding the print statement and see how it goes. I am terminating this by hitting Ctrl+C in my terminal window where the ROS launch file is runnning.
I also looked into using "try:" and "finally:" blocks. I will try that too

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried adding print statements to the code. I added print statements whenever I tried to save, please see above edited code. The print statements for NPY 1, 2, and 4 are being printed; only print statements for H5 2 is being printed (the one at the very end). So according to the print statements, the "odomData.npy" and "odomData.h5" files are being saved, but I still cannot find them anywhere in my working directory. How can I solve this so that I can view the .h5 or .npy files? Please help thank you.

Comment: The question you need to answer is, does your Ctrl-C actually fire the `ROSInterruptException`, or do you need to catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` yourself?

Comment: How do I find out if my Ctrl-C is firing `ROSInterruptException` or `KeyboardInterrupt`? Do I see what appears in my terminal?

Comment: If you see the prints, then they're being created.  You just need to find them.  Did you do `locate odomData.h5`?

Comment: Yes -- I think I realized where I blundered. The .npy file and .h5 file were being saved in the directory "~/.ros/" and not my working directory. To save them in my current working directory, do I have to put "hf = h5py.File('~/odomData.h5', 'w')"? 
What is the correct way of saving the .h5 and .npy files in my current working directory? Thank you very much.

Comment: That's actually in the ROS documentation.  They apparently set the working directory to `~/.ros` on purpose.  You might consider just learning to live with that.  As long as you know where they are, the actual location doesn't matter, right?